# How do you return a JSON object from a Java Servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

How do you return a JSON object form a Java servlet.

Previously when doing AJAX with a servlet I have returned a string. Is there a JSON object type that needs to be used, or do you just return a String that looks like a JSON object e.g.

```
String objectToReturn = "{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }";
```

Comment: Nitpick; shouldn't you want more like `{ key1: value1, key2: value2 }`?

Comment: Nitpick: what he really wants is { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }... :-)

Comment: @Ankur checkout the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909742/spring-3-2-0-web-mvc-rest-api-and-json-2-post-requests-how-to-get-it-right-on) if you decided to use Spring 3.2.0.

Comment: Nitpick: we shouldn't assume the values are Strings, so what he really wants is { "key1": value1, "key2": value2 }

Comment: These Nitpicks (esp. in this order), are epic :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I do exactly what you suggest (return a `String`).

You might consider setting the MIME type to indicate you're returning JSON, though (according to [this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) it's "application/json").

Answer (score 181):

Write the JSON object to the response object's output stream.

You should also set the content type  as follows, which will specify what you are returning:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
// Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, perform the following, it will return your json object  
out.print(jsonObject);
out.flush();
```

Comment: This helped me. As mentioned in Mark Elliot answer, **jsonObject** could be just a string formatted as a json. Remember to use double quotes, as single quotes won't give you a valid json. 

Ex.: `String jsonStr = "{\"my_key\": \"my_value\"}";`

Comment: It will be good to use response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); too

Answer (score 90):

First convert the JSON object to `String`. Then just write it out to the response writer along with content type of `application/json` and character encoding of UTF-8.

Here's an example assuming you're using [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert a Java object to a JSON string:

```
protected void doXxx(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...

    String json = new Gson().toJson(someObject);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

That's all.

#### See also:

- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax/)
- [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

Comment: I'm doing this to send response to javascript and displaying the response in alert. why is it displaying the html code inside the alert..why am i getting   the html code as response. i did the exact same thing like you said.

Comment: I have the same issue as @iLive

Answer (score 34):

> **How do you return a JSON object from a Java Servlet**

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  //create Json Object
  JsonObject json = new JsonObject();

    // put some value pairs into the JSON object .
    json.addProperty("Mobile", 9999988888);
    json.addProperty("Name", "ManojSarnaik");

    // finally output the json string       
    out.print(json.toString());
```

Comment: Depending on version, JsonObject is abstract. I created an answer to a newer implementation.

Answer (score 14):

I used [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to convert Java Object to JSON string and send as follows.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(MyObject);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
out.print(jsonString);
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 8):

Just write a string to the output stream. You might set the MIME-type to `text/javascript` (**edit**: `application/json` is apparently officialer) if you're feeling helpful. (There's a small but nonzero chance that it'll keep something from messing it up someday, and it's a good practice.)

Answer (score 8):

Gson is very  usefull for this. easier even.
here is my example:

```
public class Bean {
private String nombre="juan";
private String apellido="machado";
private List<InnerBean> datosCriticos;

class InnerBean
{
    private int edad=12;

}
public Bean() {
    datosCriticos = new ArrayList<>();
    datosCriticos.add(new InnerBean());
}
```

}

```
    Bean bean = new Bean();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json =gson.toJson(bean);
```

> out.print(json);
>
> {"nombre":"juan","apellido":"machado","datosCriticos":[{"edad":12}]}

Have to say people if yours vars are empty when using gson it wont build the json for you.Just the

> {}

Answer (score 7):

There might be a JSON object for Java coding convenience. But at last the data structure will be serialized to string. Setting a proper MIME type would be nice.

I'd suggest [JSON Java](http://www.json.org/java/) from [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Incorrect. There is usually no reason to add overhead of constructing a `String` -- output should go straight to `OutputStream`. Or, if intermediate form is needed for some reason, can use `byte[]`. Most Java JSON libraries can write directly to `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the Java version (or JDK, SDK, JRE... i dunno, im new to the Java ecosystem), the `JsonObject` is abstract. So, this is a new implementation:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

...

try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
    response.setContentType("application/json");       
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("foo", "bar").build();

    out.print(json.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

response.setContentType("text/json");

//create the JSON string, I suggest using some framework.

String your_string;

out.write(your_string.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: do I need to use getBytes("UTF-8")) or can I just return the String variable?

Comment: It's a safe programming practice to use UTF-8 for encoding the response of a web application.

Answer (score 1):

You may use bellow like.

**If you want use json array:**

1. download  **json-simple-1.1.1.jar** & add to your project class path
2. Create A class named **Model** like bellow

   ```
   public class Model {

    private String id = "";
    private String name = "";

    //getter sertter here
   }
   ```
3. In sevlet getMethod you can use like bellow

   ```
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {

     //begin get data from databse or other source
     List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
     Model model = new Model();
     model.setId("101");
     model.setName("Enamul Haque");
     list.add(model);

     Model model1 = new Model();
     model1.setId("102");
     model1.setName("Md Mohsin");
     list.add(model1);
     //End get data from databse or other source
   try {

       JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
       for (Model m : list) {
           JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
           jSONObject.put("id", m.getId());
           jSONObject.put("name", m.getName());
           ja.add(jSONObject);
       }
       System.out.println(" json ja = " + ja);
       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       response.setContentType("application/json");
       response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       response.getWriter().print(ja.toString());
       response.getWriter().flush();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
   ```
4. **Output**:

   ```
       [{"name":"Enamul Haque","id":"101"},{"name":"Md Mohsin","id":"102"}]
   ```

**I you want json Object just use like:**

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("id", "108");
        json.put("name", "Enamul Haque");
        System.out.println(" json JSONObject= " + json);
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().print(json.toString());
        response.getWriter().flush();
        // System.out.println("Response Completed... ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Above function **Output**:

```
{"name":"Enamul Haque","id":"108"}
```

Full source is given to GitHub: https://github.com/enamul95/ServeletJson.git

Answer (score 0):

Close to *BalusC* answer in 4 simple lines using Google Gson lib. Add this lines to the servlet method:

```
User objToSerialize = new User("Bill", "Gates");    
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
outputStream.print(new Gson().toJson(objToSerialize));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

By Using Gson you can send json response see below code

You can see this code

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/jsonResponse"})
public class JsonResponse extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    Student student = new Student(12, "Ram Kumar", "Male", "1234565678");
    Subject subject1 = new Subject(1, "Computer Fundamentals");
    Subject subject2 = new Subject(2, "Computer Graphics");
    Subject subject3 = new Subject(3, "Data Structures");
    Set subjects = new HashSet();
    subjects.add(subject1);
    subjects.add(subject2);
    subjects.add(subject3);
    student.setSubjects(subjects);
    Address address = new Address(1, "Street 23 NN West ", "Bhilai", "Chhattisgarh", "India");
    student.setAddress(address);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonData = gson.toJson(student);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        out.println(jsonData);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }

  }
}
```

helpful from [json response from servlet in java](https://www.ebhor.com/servlet-json-response/)