# How to get HTTP Status code and message using jquery

Tags: jquery, servlets

I am using Servlet as controller and jquery to send request to server. Following is my jquery request

```
$.post("login", {userName:$userName, password:$password}, function(data, textStatus) {
alert(textStatus);
});
```

And in server side i have written following code

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("" + strError + "");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

I want to set error message and error error status code in servlet and read the same status code in jquery. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a json encoded string from the server. [How do you return a JSON object from a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010990/how-do-you-return-a-json-object-from-a-java-servlet)

For example if you sent the following json encoded string back. 
    {'error': 'This is some error message' }

Then on the client side you would do the following

```
$.post("login", {userName:$userName, password:$password}, function(data, textStatus) {
    alert(data.error); // your error message will show up here in the data object 
 },'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

In a java servlet, to set the HTTP status, you have to use the following:

```
response.setStatus( code );
```

The `code` part can be several things like `HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND` to emulate an error 404 (page not found). A exhaustive list can be found [here](http://javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/http_status_code.shtml).

On the jQuery side, you can use the following:

```
$.post( 'login', { /* ... */ }, function( data, textStatus, xhrObject ) {
    // You can read the status returned with
    xhrObject.status;
} );
```

I guess the `textStatus` variable holds the status, but the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) doesn't say anything about what it can return.

Comment: If I set status in servlet i am not getting status code in jquery. I did the same as you suggested now.

Comment: You tried to see in the debugger what the `textStatus` variable had in it? Same for `xhrObject`?

Comment: Debugger doesnt come inside that function if i set status code. if i dont set status code then it is showing status code as 200. I have written the following in servlet response.setStatus(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("" + strError + "");
            out.flush();
            out.close();