# Getting Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value HI. of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

Here is my RegisterActivity.java:

```
        package com.example.loginactivity;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
        import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
        {

    private EditText mid, mpass, mnumber;
    private Button  mRegister;


       private ProgressDialog pDialog;


       JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


       private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.0.101:8080/trialandroid1/registered.jsp";

        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        mid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
        mpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        mnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);

        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new CreateUser().execute();

    }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Registreing...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String id1=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.id)).getText().toString();
            String password1=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
            String number1=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.number)).getText().toString();

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id1));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password1));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number",number1));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success element
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

My Register.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
      android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/header"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingBottom="5dip"
     android:paddingTop="5dip" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/myText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="2.53"
         android:gravity="center"
       android:lines="1"
         android:text="WELCOME TO SVIT APP"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
          android:typeface="sans"
         android:textColor="@color/myText" 

    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
     android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip" 
    android:paddingRight="15dip" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true"/>
                <!-- Logo Start-->        
         <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
         android:src="@drawable/logo" />
                <!-- Logo Ends -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->
        <!-- Footer Start -->

        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <LinearLayout

          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:layout_below="@id/header">
          <!-- Full Name Label -->
          <!--  Email Label -->

          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Login ID:"/>
          <!-- Password Label -->

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/id"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="text" />

          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Password"/>
           <EditText
              android:id="@+id/password"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="textPassword" />
             <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Contact_no."/>
                <EditText
     android:id="@+id/number"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:ems="10"
     android:inputType="text" />

          <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Register New Account"/>
          <!-- Link to Login Screen -->


        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Registration Form Ends -->
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My registered.jsp is:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String uname=request.getParameter("username");
String pass= request.getParameter("password");
String contact=request.getParameter("contact");


 try {
     Connection con = null;

         String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userreg";

                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "123456");

//out.println("HI.");


                        Statement s = null;

                        s = con.createStatement();
                        String s1 =  "insert into login(username,password,phone) values('"+uname+"','"+pass+"','"+contact+"')";
                          s.executeUpdate(s1);
                        //  out.println("HI.");
                           out.println("{'status':'success'}");

                 }

    catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                                 }


%>
```

I am getting the above error while registering from android app. The logcat is:

```
03-30 15:51:20.958: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23142): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-30 15:53:19.808: D/request!(23142): starting
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/JSON Parser(23142): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of 
03-30 15:53:20.138: W/dalvikvm(23142): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2bf9180)
03-30 15:53:20.138: I/Process(23142): Sending signal. PID: 23142 SIG: 9
03-30 15:53:20.138: D/AndroidRuntime(23142): procName from cmdline: com.example.loginactivity
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.loginactivity
03-30 15:53:20.138: D/AndroidRuntime(23142): file written successfully with content: com.example.loginactivity StringBuffer : ;com.example.loginactivity
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at com.example.loginactivity.RegisterActivity$CreateUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:118)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at com.example.loginactivity.RegisterActivity$CreateUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-30 15:53:20.138: E/AndroidRuntime(23142):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Have you checked the received json string ? is it a valid json string ?

Comment: I am unable to receive any json string..

Comment: Are you sure, you are not getting any string from the web-service ? See line 5 of logcat.

Comment: yes am sure about it.. am unable to get anything

Comment: i edited my logcat output

Comment: Have you tested the url directly ? And try logging your request to see if you are receiving correct data.

Comment: What is line 118 in RegisterActivity.java ?

Comment: @MTahir: Directly am able to send data to my database from the jsp page.

Comment: @Swayam: there is no line 118 in the RegisterActivity.java

Comment: `com.example.loginactivity.RegisterActivity$CreateUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:118)` is what your LogCat says, and that is where the problem lies.

Comment: @Swayam: this is line 118 : Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Comment: That means that the `json` object is null, which leads to the NPE.

Comment: @Swayam: yes i saw nothing is going inside bufferreader ... Checked thru debugging.. but i dont knw how to solve it

Comment: Your login URL is correct? Are you sure about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not returning json from your JSP script. You have now commented the 
'HI', that I had earlier mentioned, which is not a valid json. You should return a valid json response like following from your jsp script.

For success

```
    {"status":"success"}
```

For failure

```
    {"status":"failed","msg":"An error message explaining what went wrong"}
```

For your help, see the following answers for returning json from jsp

[Return JSON from one JSP to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697364)

[Returning JSON response from Servlet to Javascript/JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154845)

I hope it will help you.

In your jsp script, check if any parameter is empty or has not valid value then return a json that identifies the error, and also if there occurs any problem while executing query, check and return a message that will help the user. And if all goes well simply return a success message.

Comment: I can actually enter data from the jsp page. there is no problem in it.

Comment: For simplicity, just print out the success json string ie. `{"status":"success"}`  just after executing query, and check your android app.

Comment: I have added a line to print json in case of success, try it now

Comment: may i know what problem are you facing now ? At the moment it is not possible, but after 4,5 hours I'll be able to help via teamviewer.

Comment: What is printed/displayed when you test this code in browser ?

Comment: @riachwdry23: Is it working or still getting error ?