# how to send an object with URLConnection?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

My goal  is to send a object from a client application  to a server using URLConnection The object User :

```
 Public class user {
     String nom;
     Integer id ;
     boolean sex;

    }
```

I don't want to send it field by field but as an object.

Comment: `Serializable`+ `ObjectOutputStream`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send the object with an `ObjectOutputStream`.
A requirement for this would be that you implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    ......
}
```

Now to send an User-Object:

```
User usr = new User();    

Url url;
HttpURLConnection conn;
ObjectOutputStream objout;
try {
    url = new Url("http://192.160.1.1");
    conn  = (HttpURLConnection) url.getConnection();

    conn.setDoOutput(true); //this is to enable writing
    conn.setDoInput(true);  //this is to enable reading

    out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(usr);
    out.close();
}
```

Now that object will be sent to the specified url.

Comment: Small typo: objout variable shoud be replaced with out

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json](http://json.org/) to achieve your requirement.

In addition, followings may help you for learning Json.

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/

[How do you return a JSON object from a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010990/how-do-you-return-a-json-object-from-a-java-servlet)