# get value from servlet using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I want to fetch object from servlet.

I try below code but I get "[object Object]" . I want "Description" value.

I got out in browser when I run http://www.host.com/f/ServletToJSP1/*

o/p {"Description":"Nutanix provides disruptive datacenter infrastructure solutions that are hyper-efficient, massively scalable and elegantly simple."}

in console log :Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

How can I do that ?

```
jsp code
                  $.ajax({
                        url : 'ServletToJSP1', 
                        type : 'GET',
                        dataType : 'json', 
                        success : function(response) {
                            //response = $.parseJSON(response);
                            alert(response);
                        },
                        error : function(error) {
                            //error handling....
                            alert(error);
                        }
                    });
```

**servlet code**

```
JSONObject objTw = new JSONObject();
      objTw.put("Description", "Nutanix provides disruptive datacenter infrastructure solutions that are hyper-efficient, massively scalable and elegantly simple.");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("application/json"); 
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); 
  out.println(objTw);
```

Comment: try to see the content of this object from the console.

Comment: @FaceOfJock:Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: Check this out may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/2012031/2291134

Answer (score 0):

Access the `description` property on the response object.

```
          $.ajax({
                url : 'ServletToJSP1', 
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json', 
                success : function(response) {
                    //response = $.parseJSON(response);
                    alert(response.Description);
                },
                error : function(error) {
                    //error handling....
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I try this get "undefined"

Comment: If you execute `console.log(response);` in the success handler what does the console log?

Comment: Are you using a Google library such as Maps? Or loading jQuery from the Google CDN?

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing in Chrome?
You can open the dev tools with CTRL+SHIFT+I then open the Console.

Instead of alert(respone) try console.log(response) to have a deeper look into the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
success : function(response) {
                  alert(response[0].Description);
                },
```

and in your servlet code try to add `out.flush();`

Comment: No this not help . alert is not come you ans is more far

Comment: @Nick what that should mean ? Please take your time to spell the words completely and to describe accurately what is happening. BTW, are you saying that the alert is not reached ? But it's the first row of the "success" result... where do you see the [Object object] then ?