# Get request object, when JSP page is submitted using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I submit JSP page with AJAX,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = $('#form1');
    form.submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var x = data;    
                $('#result').attr("value", x);    
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

In my Servlet,

```
request.setAttribut("test","asd");
```

is used.

Now I want to use `request.getAttribute("test");` in my JSP page but I can't find.

Comment: do you want to pass a variable back to the jsp from the servlet?

Comment: yes it is just example
i am pass i variable value from jsp to servlet and 
process on that variable and return HaseMap from servlet to JSP

Comment: so u mean u arent recieving data in the success?am i right?

Comment: i am receive data as string i need to get object of map from ajax

Comment: the link darian has refered you should have helped you..did u try it?

Comment: Yes that link i refer there is conver map to json and then after return json and recevi json and manipulate that json...

it may be usefull but i dies not have enough knowledge of JSON
but it may be helpful

Comment: dont think its possible then..Also as u said request.getAttribute isnt working..hope u have an `e` at the end of `request.setAttribute` :).Coz if u dont pass it as JSON u will get a markup of the servlet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the serialized content of the form here:

```
data: form.serialize()
```

Make sure that inside your form you have a `<input>` field with `name="test"`. Then inside your servlet you could retrieve the value using the `getParameter` method:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String test = request.getParameter("test");
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: in servlet i am also write request.setAttribute("test1","asd");
and i need that request value in jsp
but i can't get request attribut in jsp which servlet set

Comment: because my requirement is send HaseMap object from servlet to jsp when  page is submit using ajax

Comment: Since this is an AJAX call to the servlet, the page will not reload. So any changes you might be doing in your servlet will not reflect to the UI unless you manually reflect them in the `success` callback. Ideally when working with AJAX your server side action should either return only some partial HTML that you could replace in the DOM or JSON.

Comment: ok so it means i can't get map object from servlet in jsp file

Comment: The `data` parameter that is passed to the `success` function will contain the result of the servlet execution. If you are rendering some JSP then it will contain the markup of this JSP. You should modify your servlet so that it returns JSON result. Then you will be able to assign it to the value of the corresponding input field. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2012031/29407