# Async task's messages exchange with Java Servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets, android-asynctask

I have a simple app communicating with its Servlet backend through an Async task. 
I have some trouble understanding how the messages are wrapped up and how to manipulate the data structures of these messages. 
What I want to do is to receive either multiple objects, or multiple heterogeneous information anyway. 
My code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ArrayList<Tour> m_tours;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Please use the form to POST to this url");

    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    String order = req.getParameter("order");
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    if (order == null) {
        resp.getWriter().println("Please enter a name");
    }

      resp.getWriter().println("yay name received");
      ArrayList<Tour> m_tours = getTours(); //returns a populated ArrayList of custom Tour objects
      resp.getWriter().print(m_tours);
}
    private void getTours(){
        //some code here
    }
}`
```

And my Async task class:

```
class ServletPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {
private Context context;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
    context = params[0].first;
    String order = params[0].second;

    String[] url = new String[3];
    url[0] = "http://192.168.169.85:8080/hello";
    url[1] = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/hello";
    url[2] = "http://192.168.1.102:8080/hello";
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url[2]);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order", order));
        try {
            // Add name data to request
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
                return "Error: " + response
                        .getStatusLine()
                        .getStatusCode() + " " + response
                        .getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       String result1 = "Response: "+result;
           Toast.makeText(context, result1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The response message returns ArrayList as text:

```
 Response: yay name received
 packagename@objectkey1
 packagename@objectkey2
 packagename@objectkey3
 ...
 packagename@objectkeyn
```

But instead, what I want is to store it as it is, as an ArrayList.
How can I configure my Async task to receive my m_tours ArrayList and store it somewhere for further use?
Furthermore, how can I configure it to receive multiple objects?

*** EDIT ***

I've tried by using Gson as suggested by @orip, setting the Async task as follows:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
    context = params[0].first;
    String order = params[0].second;

    String[] url = new String[3];
    url[0] = "http://192.168.169.85:8080/hello";
    url[1] = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/hello";
    url[2] = "http://192.168.1.102:8080/hello";
    // HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://semiotic-art-88319.appspot.com/hello");
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); //127.0.0.1 - 10.201.19.153
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url[2]);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order", order));

    try {
        // Add name data to request
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
        return "Error: " + response
                .getStatusLine()
                .getStatusCode() + " " + response
                .getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String jsonResponse) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    tours = (gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, Tours.class));
    Toast.makeText(context, jsonResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and on the Server side:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    String asyncMessage = req.getParameter("order");
    if(asyncMessage.equals("tours")){
        m_tours = getTours();  //ArrayList<Tour> m_tours;
        Tours tours = new Tours(m_tours);
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print(new Gson().toJson(tours));
        out.flush();

        resp.getWriter().print(m_tours);
    }

}
```

but I get an error:

```
03-23 13:27:09.523  32387-32387/madapps.bicitourbo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: madapps.bicitourbo, PID: 32387
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 692 path $
        at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:786)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:776)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
        at madapps.bicitourbo.ServletPostAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ServletPostAsyncTask.java:92)
        at madapps.bicitourbo.ServletPostAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ServletPostAsyncTask.java:36)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 692 path $
```

This error occurs on the line:

```
Tour tours = (gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, Tours.class));
```

What do I do wrong?

*** EDIT2 ***
Solved:

The error: `Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON` was due to the fact that I was calling `resp.getWriter().print()` two times, as suggested by @orip. Thank you!

Comment: Is `resp.getWriter().print(m_tours);` still in the code? Should it be?

Comment: oh right, no it wasn't supposed to be there. I removed it, and now it's working;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the servlet's content type to `application/json` and return a JSON string (e.g using Gson or Jackson to serialize the result.

On the Android side you can deserialize the JSON string, either using Android's built-in JSON classes or (better) using the same libraries you used in your servlet.

For example, if `Tour` is something like:

```
public class Tour {
  // some simple int/string/list fields
}
```

You can build a response class like:

```
public class Tours {
  private List<Tour> tours;
  // ...
}
```

Then on the server side (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010990/how-do-you-return-a-json-object-from-a-java-servlet), I'm using [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) here):

```
List<Tour> listOfTours = ...;
Tours tours = new Tours(listOfTours);
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print((new Gson()).toJson(tours));
out.flush();
```

And on the client side:

```
String jsonResponse = ...;
Tours tours = (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonResponse, Tours.class);
```

There are some optimizations to be made, but that could get you started.
Also, consider using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for your HTTP connections instead of using `HttpClient`, you'll probably end up with simpler and more robust code.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions! It worked smoothly; but now, in Servlet I am setting the content type to "application/json" just after sending the message "Response: yay message received". Therefore, how do I discriminate, within the response received by the Async task, between the String message and the serialized json in String format? Because I am getting them all together. 

In short: how do I separate my string from my json?

Comment: Return just the json. If you want to add a string field or a success status, add them to the response type (e.g to Tours in my example)

Comment: Ok, done, but I get this error `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true)` as posted in my last edit. What do I do wrong?

Comment: You'll need to post the json somewhere so we can see what's wrong (can scrub it manually for privacy if needed).

Comment: Orip, thank you, your suggestions worked. I only have one more question: how can I pass the so created response Tours object containing List<Tour> list, to the class where I call my Async Task from?? Anytime I try to get that object from the class where I execute the command `ServletPostAsyncTask s = new ServletPostAsyncTask();
            s.execute(new Pair<Context, String>(ListViewPrenota.this, "tours"));` I get an error as if the object would be empty...

Comment: You get the result in `onPostExecute`, assuming you return the list in `doInBackground`. You can then use it to save in a field, persist to disk, update UI, etc.