# Ajax how can I refresh a drop down after call servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have the following jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${vlocomotoras}" var="vl" varStatus="i">

    <select class="regimenFrenoLocomotora" id="regimenFrenoLocomotora" name="regimenFrenoLocomotora" onchange="calcularDocumentoTren();">
        <option value="P" ${"P" == v1.regimenFrenoLocomotoras ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>P</option>
        <option value="G" ${"G" == v1.regimenFrenoLocomotoras ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>G</option>

</select>

</c:forEach>
```

I have the following  ajax  post to a servlet

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/copernico/SrvRenfeSituacion",
            data: {
            "arrayLocomotora[]" : arrayLocomotora,
            todo:todo,
            fecha:fecha,
            tren:tren
          },
            error:function(){
            console.log("ERROR");
          },
            success:function(responseText){
            alert('responseText ');
            alert(responseText);
            alert("Success");
          }
        });
```

This is the servlet

```
req.setAttribute("vlocomotoras", locomotoras);
```

Now I want to refresh the drop down with the new values of vlocomotoras. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have your servlet return a json array with the data you need. [See this question for doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010990/how-do-you-return-a-json-object-from-a-java-servlet).

(In the ajax call, set `dataType="json"` for the call to expect a json object as response)

Once you get the json object in the ajax response, you can replace the `OPTION` tags inside the `SELECT` using jQuery (`empty()` and `appendTo()`).