# How to return 404 not found in json format using restful api in java?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

i would like to implement an exception handler for restful api if the uri is not matched.
For example:
 url is
`localhost:8080\test\generateNumber` will return
`{"response_code":"200"}`

and
if the url is wrong for example:
`localhost:8080\test\generateNumber2` will return
`{"response_code":"404","message":"uri not found"}`

i have no idea on how to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: I hope this will help [Check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010990/how-do-you-return-a-json-object-from-a-java-servlet)

Comment: not exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using Spring?

In that case you can use @ExceptionHandler like this:

```
@RestController
public class Example1Controller {

    @GetMapping(value = "/testExceptionHandler", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Response testExceptionHandler(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean exception)
            throws BusinessException {
        if (exception) {
            throw new BusinessException("BusinessException in testExceptionHandler");
        }
        return new Response("OK");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
    public Response handleException(BusinessException e) {
        return new Response(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

And get a message in response.

More - in [this manual](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring).